# Regular expression: re.findall() for set of all alphabetic words

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to using re.findall() function to test on a sentence that has a set of all alphabetic words. Here's my code:

```
import re
s = 'Hello from the other side'
lst = re.findall('[:alpha:]', s)
print (lst)
```

Any suggestions on how I can change the code?

Comment: What is your language?

Comment: looks like python

Answer (score 5):

Python doesn't support the POSIX `:alpha:`.  Write this instead:

```
re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+', s)
```

Avoid use of `\w+` which accepts underscores and numbers in addition to alpha characters.  The only real advantage of `\w+` is that it works with the 
 `re.LOCALE` flag.

When I parse natural sentences to extract entire words, I usually expand the allowed characters to also allow hyphens and apostrophes:

```
re.findall(r"[A-Za-z\-\']+", s)
```

This will accept words like "don't" and "re-invent" and "cul-de-sac" but will reject numbers, underscores, whitespace, quote marks, and other punctuation.

Comment: There's no need to escape these characters in a class, `re.findall(r"[-'A-Za-z]+", s)` is equally fine and more readable, +1 for the `re.LOCALE` flag.